How to contribute a bulk coretime region to an instantaneous coretime pool to earn rewards and so it remains renewable indefinitely?
If you buy a Kusama Coretime core, and you we want to use your core to run a parachain, it seems you need to deposit 40 KSM to reserve a ParaID, and then you have to place a reserve deposit of ~1087.576042 KSM, to register that ParaID even with just the add-collator parachain template code as calculated here How to calculate required "reserved deposit" to register a parachain on Kusama with adder-collator genesis state and code?.

Note: Unfortunately I am not certain whether that is correct, as most of the KSM I have access to is locked in staking so there's not enough time to unlock it to use it before the period of the region I have access to ends, and I don't want trigger taxable events in order to buy ~1100 KSM unless I know for certain that the error message shown in the link above of system.ExtrinsicFailedbalances.LiquidityRestrictions is truly because I need that higher available balance to place the reserve deposit, and not due to some other reason. So as for using that core that I currently have access to, to running a parachain with it, I think I'll just buy a second core, since then I'll have more time to unstake some KSM to be able to cover those reserve deposits.

It seems I need to have assigned the core I have access to, to a ParaID using Final Finality in order to be able to renew it (since in the Lastic.xyz UI it says Note: If you have a full core it is better to choose Final Finality, if you do you will be able to renew your core.)
But I noticed that Lastic.xyz doesn't yet allow us to contribute our region to the instantaneous coretime pool yet, but that RegionX does offer that here.
If you choose to contribute your region to the instantaneous coretime pool using RegionX, it gives you the option of choosing a finality of either Final or Provisional, and says that Finally pooled regions can no longer be managed. They will not be displayed on the Region Management page anymore.
Question: So if I'm looking to just contribute the current region number that I have access to, to an instantaneous coretime pool (such as that offered by RegionX) on Kusama Coretime parachain, but where I want to be able to renew my contribution of that region to the instantaneous coretime pool indefinitely so I can keep earning rewards. In order to achieve that would I choose Final or Provisional finality for pooling that core? And would that only be possible if I had first assigned the core I have access to, to a ParaID using Final Finality, or wouldn't it be necessary to have assigned the region to a ParaID?

Note: According to associated Substrate tests in the Broker pallet of the Polkadot SDK, here it shows that it might be necessary to use Final for it to be renewable. It also seems that Provisional allows the core to be reassignable to different tasks (ParaIDs) here


There seem to be multiple questions, so I will try to answer them one by one.
Yes, the registration cost is fixed at the maximum amount, even for runtimes as simple as the adder collator. The reason for this is to prevent users from initially registering a runtime with small code, paying proportionally a smaller price, and then upgrading the code to the maximum size essentially for free. You can read more about this here: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/3020
When pooling a region, there are indeed two options: to assign it finally or provisionally. However, pooled regions cannot be renewed. The only difference between final and provisional pooling is that you won't pay the transaction fee for pooling if it is final. Given that transaction fees are pretty low, I suggest using provisional finality since you can later use the same region for something else.
On RegionX, we still don't offer a UI for claiming rewards; however, that is on our TODO list. So until then you will probably have to rely on PJS for claiming rewards.

Thanks for your response. Could it be a valid RFC to allow users to specify what maximum size they forecast they'll need when registering a ParaID, and then preventing them from performing runtime upgrades to sizes larger than they specified, and allow them to update their registration of that ParaID if they find they need to increase the size they're allowed to use?

So currently a region lasts for 28 days, and you can't renew it if you pool. If you use provisional pooling a few days before your region ends what happens to that core when it's region ends, do you just lose the core and stop earning from the pool since it can't be renewed so you have to bid on it to try to buy it again and compete with others for it using dutch auction, and then choose to pool it for another 28 days. It costs ~25 KSM to buying a new core using dutch auction, or for legacy parachains they can renew the region of their core for 5 KSM

The idea you mentioned could maybe make sense. However, at that point, it would probably be a better idea to have a dynamic cost for storing code on-chain. I would suggest reading this discussion: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/2372#discussion_r1461873933

The core will be offered for sale, so you would have to bid on it like everyone else.
